# Counting number of special characters in a given file

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Hy, 
In the result, the number of zeros and ones isn't the same.

And i don't find where is the problem.

Can any One help me please?

```
        //Main {
        int bufferSize = 10240; //10KB
        int fileSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024; //10MB
        Random r = new Random();

        //Writing 0 and 1 into file
        File file = new File("test.txt");
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file, false); //this false means, every time we want to write into file, it will destructs what was before
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(bw);

        for(int i=0; i<1000; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<1000; j++){
                if(r.nextBoolean()){
                    pw.write("0 ");
                }else{
                    pw.write("1 ");
                }
            }
            pw.write("\n");
        }

        System.out.println("End of writing into file : " + file.getName() + ", in : " + file.getAbsolutePath() + ", and its size : " + file.length());
        pw.close();


        //Read from file, and counting number of zeros and ones
        System.out.println("Reading from file : Scanner method");
        Scanner sc = null;
        //sc = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file)));
        sc = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), "UTF-8"), bufferSize));
        int countZeros=0;
        int countOnes=0;
        StringTokenizer st = null;
        String temp = null;

        //Start counting time
        long debut  = System.nanoTime();
        while(sc.hasNext()){
            st = new StringTokenizer(sc.next(), " ");
            while(st.hasMoreTokens() ){
                temp = st.nextToken();
                if(temp.compareTo("0")==0 && !Character.isSpaceChar(temp.charAt(0))){
                    countZeros++;
                }
                else if(temp.compareTo("1")==0 && !Character.isSpaceChar(temp.charAt(0))){
                    countOnes++;
                }
            }
        }
        //End counting time
        long end  = System.nanoTime() - debut;
        sc.close();
        System.out.println("Number of Zeros : " + countZeros);
        System.out.println("Number of Ones : " + countOnes);
        System.out.println("Total of zeros and Ones : " + (countZeros+countOnes));
        System.out.println("Duration of counting zeros and ones : " + end/1000000 + "ms");


        System.out.println("************");
        System.out.println("Reading from file : BufferedReader method");

        countZeros=0;
        countOnes=0;
        st=null;
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), "UTF-8"), bufferSize);
        String[] tempLigne = null;
        //Start counting time
        debut  = System.nanoTime();
        for(int i=0; (i=br.read())>-1;){
            tempLigne = br.readLine().split(" ");
            for(int j=0; j<tempLigne.length; j++){
                if(tempLigne[j].equals("0")){
                    countZeros++;
                }else if(tempLigne[j].equals("1")){
                    countOnes++;
                }
            }
        }
        //End counting time
        end  = System.nanoTime() - debut;
        br.close();
        System.out.println("Number of Zeros : " + countZeros);
        System.out.println("Number of Ones : " +  countOnes);
        System.out.println("Total of zeros and Ones : " + (countZeros+countOnes));
        System.out.println("Duration of counting zeros and ones : " + end/1000000 + "ms");

    }

}
```

//Output

```
End of writing into file : test.txt, in : C:\Users\youness\workspace\ScannerFile\test.txt, and its size : 1990656
Reading from file : Scanner method
Number of Zeros : 499807
Number of Ones : 500193
Total of zeros and Ones : 1000000
Duration of counting zeros and ones : 1020ms
************
Reading from file : BufferedReader method
Number of Zeros : 499303
Number of Ones : 499697
Total of zeros and Ones : 999000
Duration of counting zeros and ones : 177ms
```

Thank you,
Best Reagrds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in the code here:

```
for(int i=0; (i=br.read())>-1;){
    tempLigne = br.readLine().split(" ");
    for(int j=0; j<tempLigne.length; j++){
        if(tempLigne[j].equals("0")){
            countZeros++;
        }else if(tempLigne[j].equals("1")){
            countOnes++;
        }
    }
}
```

`br.read()` actually [reads one character](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#read()). Instead of processing that character, you discard the result by reading the remaining whole line by `br.readline()`.

Since there are 1000 lines in the file and you discarded the first character of each line, you end up 1000 characters less.

You may change your `for(int i=0; (i=br.read())>-1;)` to `while (br.ready())`. When the br is empty, the loop will terminate

Comment: Ah ok, yes, that works.so the problem wasn't in the Scanner class.

thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

You're generating 0 and 1 values using Random class.

This class generates a random distribution so it doesn't ensures that the number of 0 and 1 characters generated will be the same, because it's a **random** generator.

Only if you generate an infinite amount of numbers then there will be the same number of 0s and 1s.

The more characters you generate, the closer the two values will be.